# Application project assigned during interview in a different language

Tags: interviewing, software-development

I interviewed for a junior level C# developer job. After my technical interview they sent me assignment to build a GUI application in python that will take a csv file and convert to a sql database. The program should then query the data. I had 3 days to complete and turn in the assignment. I was able to learn python (although still junior at it) and complete the assignment in two days.

My question is: Why would they assign me something knowing that I have never programmed in Python? Also, Python isn't even in the job description.....

Comment: did they maybe send you the wrong test? did you ask?

Comment: I stated to them before they assigned that I have never programmed in python but they said they would send documentation relevant to the assignment. It was just the official python documentation.

Comment: weird, huh? I guess they're checking your core ability to solve problems. If you're quite keen on C# you might want to ask them what language you'll be coding in in the in-person job interview

Comment: Maybe they're confused and think you applied for a Python role or they're confused about your experience, maybe there's indeed quite a bit of Python involved in the role, maybe they thought you'd be a better fit for the Python role or maybe they're just testing how quickly you can pick up new things. We can only speculate, only they know the real reason.

Comment: Hmm I am wondering if this happens often when applying for software developer jobs. This was the first time I was asked to develop a application out of all the jobs I have interviewed for.

Comment: I've taken and given quite a few coding tests, and IMO the expected language should be crystal clear. If it's not, then ask. When giving tests, I have the interviewee select their best language within the options. Nothing wrong with learning Python, but it's clearly not what you had expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they were aware beforehand that you didn't know Python then it's possible that the "real" test was seeing how quickly you can adapt to and pick up new technologies.

You stated this was after the technical interview so presumably that was primarily focused on C# If you have another interview round after this then it may be worth inquiring as to what languages and technologies they envisage the role using, if nothing else to ensure that it is still a role you'd be happy to undertake.